# Only change text on a new click, instead of real time in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to keep my output text only show when I the new search button is clicked.

Right now, I have a results bar that show the search term that a user is looking for, initially is hidden, but when a search is entered you see the results bar with the term.

the problem is as users enter a new search, the text on the result bar changes, and what I would like to do, is to only have the text change when they click the search button again.

[image]

seems simple in premise, but I am having a hard time figuring it out.

```js
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      searchedTerm: '',
    }  
  }
  
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ 
      ...this.state, 
      searchedTerm: event.target.value,
    })
  }
  
 <ProductList         
  list={list} 
  term={searchedTerm}
  hideResultsBar={hideResultsBar} /> 
  
  
  
  
//different component

export default props => {
  const { hideResultsBar, term, list } = props;
  return(
    <div>
      {
        hideResultsBar ? null : <SearchResultBar term={term} />
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `onChange` event, you'll need to move your `setState` logic into a submit handler when you click the search icon or press enter in the search field. You'll also need to assign a `ref` to the search input so that you can grab the value from it:

```
handleSearchSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({
      searchedTerm: this.searchInput.value,
    })
  }

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" ref={ ref => this.searchInput = ref } />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: they could still keep it as a controlled input by just adding another property to state for the input value and only updating `searchedTerm` onClick/onSubmit as you have it

Answer (score 0):

You could add another property to your state for the showing and hiding of the results and whenever the text is changed it hides the results, and clicking the button shows them, e.g:

```
class App extends Component {    
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = { 
        searchedTerm: '',
        hideResultsBar: true
      }  
    }

    handleChange = event => {
      //you don't need to set all items with ...this.state
      //like you would with redux
      this.setState({ 
        searchedTerm: event.target.value,
        hideResultsBar: true
      });
    }

    handleSearchClick = () => {
       this.setState({ hideResultsBar: false });
    }
  }

 <ProductList         
  list={list} 
  term={searchedTerm}
  hideResultsBar={hideResultsBar} 
 />    

export default props => {
  const { term, list, hideResultsBar  } = props;

  return(
    <div>
      {
        hideResultsBar ? null : <SearchResultBar term={term} />
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```